# Want to execute single step in selenium web driver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to do automation of web application.(I am using eclipse)
In my test, I have written the code to login the page by credential, then click some links and go to a particular page.Now on that page i am filling fields through drop down and all and its not working.

So My question is if i changing my code to work with drop down,then to test this again i need to run test case from starting.Means again it it will login page will load and go through various links and then reach to that page.
So can not directly execute that steps only like we do in selenium IDE???

Again and again executing from starting is really screwing my time...??

Is there any way/shortcut?? Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: I have not installed any selenium server in my eclipse

Comment: With Eclipse I do not think you have any option. It will always run from step 1.

Comment: IF no option, then really its very difficult to do automation with webdriver.I can't believe it...

Comment: Just a thought. Test cases _should_ be as short as possible to test only the things they're supposed to. I'm writing my tests using Python, so I can check if my changes are alright using Python interpreter with healthy webdriver instance

Comment: BTW, try to write some 'tricky login' method. In my test project I have a separate test for login, in other cases, where the logged in user's needed, I use cookies to go around the sign-in form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium IDE is in-browser, it's then normal you can run at any step. But if your cookies have expired, you'll have to reauthent. It's not a Selenium problem, it's how websites work.
In your tests, you'll always have to start from scratch if your cases involve athent process, unless you manage to get a fine control over your cookies.

You can always make a quick http call to the website you want to connect to with `HTTPClient` for example, just to get the cookie back, then use it in webdriver with something like

```
driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("foo", "bar", "www.domain.com", "/", null));
```

then go to the page you need. Notice that this solution solves the Authent problem only, and does not control the ***state*** of the tested web-application (data previously posted, etc...).

At our company, we make an extensive use of selenium, and have a lot of tests relying on it, it's therefore a problem we know something about and we are aware of the frustation it can cause.

We use a pretty different solution to get a productivity boost on tests.
In fact, we're using a [`Groovy Shell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell)-based solution which allows us to go back and forth while developping the tests and keep our browsers open. `Groovy` is a JVM scripting language that is really easy for a Java dev (almost all Java code is valid Groovy code) and it's really dynamic.

So you can download groovy, run groovy shell (`groovysh` is the command), then line by line you can launch and interact with the browser xhile your written code is saved to a buffer. When you've done with your test, export the code and put it in Eclipse. It's faster than restarting every time from scratch. Magic lines for starting with selenium are

```
groovy.grape.Grape.grab(autoDownload: true, group : 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', module : 'selenium-firefox-driver', version : '2.37.1')
import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*
driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver.get("http://my-website.com")
```

From this point, the browser window is always open, and you develop right in groovy (or java). It's like a selenium-ide, but in groovy, and can be integrated in your developement workflow (but there is a bit of work to do)
This example works for Firefox (as you've probably guessed ;-)) but you can adapt it as you like. We have from this constructed a bunch of tools to develop our tests quickly and iteratively. We found this to be a great savior.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you described, the tests will always return to step 1, therefore, you need to execute your automation suite from the beginning.

Tip for the future, separate your test cases to shorter ones (as Alexander suggested), so you if you need, you can easily use only the cases that needed and relevant to the module you currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing different answer..runs from first step...
And my kind advice is that to use a break point in eclipse at which u r guess of failing...and run the eclipse program in debug mode vth continuously pressing F6 key.
The excecution will be slowed and display will be step by step mode which u can easily trace the exact location at which u r code is breaking...